# How to install Haveged and RNGD on Android

Tags: rooting, android-emulator

I was reading about those two tools on rngd (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rng-tools) and haveged (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged), and i wonder how to install them on android rooted phone ? and does that need other tools/software to install it.

thanks.